# AWS cloudformation fail instance not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-ebs

I am trying to create an Amazon EC2 instance then create an Amazon EBS volume and attach it to the instance. I am using a CloudFormation template for this. Unfortunately the stack creation is failing when attaching newly created volume to the instance with the following error:

> Instance 'i-01eebc8c9c492c035' is not 'running'. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: IncorrectState; Request ID: 635572fd-dd25-4a02-9306-6e22f88e13dc)

What I do not understand is, when the instance creation is complete, that means the instance is up and running. How can this error be possible?

I am using the following CloudFormation template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "single instance template",
  "Parameters": {
    "InstanceType": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.micro"
    },
    "InstanceName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test_CFT"
    },
    "RootVolumeSize": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "50"
    },
    "Volume1Size": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "8"
    },
    "Region": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "us-east-2"
    },
    "AMIID": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "ami-8c122be9"
    },
    "SubnetIds": {
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": "subnet-595e7422"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIDs": {
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": "sg-082faee8335351537"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": {
          "Ref": "AMIID"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        },
        "KeyName": "thehope",
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
            "DeviceIndex": "0",
            "SubnetId": {
              "Fn::Select": [
                0,
                {
                  "Ref": "SubnetIds"
                }
              ]
            },
            "GroupSet": {
              "Ref": "SecurityGroupIDs"
            }
          }
        ],
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "Ebs": {
              "VolumeSize": {
                "Ref": "RootVolumeSize"
              },
              "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
              "VolumeType": "gp2"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "InstanceName"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Volume1": {
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "Instance",
            "AvailabilityZone"
          ]
        },
        "Encrypted": "False",
        "Size": {
          "Ref": "Volume1Size"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "New_volume"
          }
        ],
        "VolumeType": "gp2"
      },
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume"
    },
    "VolumeAttachment1": {
      "Properties": {
        "Device": "/dev/xvdb",
        "InstanceId": {
          "Ref": "Instance"
        },
        "VolumeId": {
          "Ref": "Volume1"
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment"
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "InstanceId": {
      "Description": "InstanceId of the instance",
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "Instance"
      }
    },
    "AZ": {
      "Description": "Availability Zone of the instance",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "Instance",
          "AvailabilityZone"
        ]
      }
    },
    "PrivateIP": {
      "Description": "PrivateIP of the instance",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "Instance",
          "PrivateIp"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is my first time posting in the stack over flow.sorry for the view. following is the Cloudformation Template. https://github.com/varun1020/practice_all/blob/master/cloudformation.json

Comment: Have you tried adding a [DependsOn Attribute - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) to the Volume, pointing to the EC2 instance?

Comment: I tried just now, It did not work and I also noticed that by default the instance is in stopped state when launched. how to change that behavior to running ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating new volumes, it would be easier to **simply specify the volumes as part of the instance** rather than specifying an Amazon EBS volume and then attaching it to the instance.

From [Amazon EC2 Block Device Mapping Property - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html):

> This example sets the EBS-backed root device (/dev/sda1) size to 50 GiB, and another EBS-backed device mapped to /dev/sdm that is 100 GiB in size.

```
"BlockDeviceMappings" : [
   {
      "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
      "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "50" }
   },
   {
      "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdm",
      "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "100" }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response john. I want to encrypt the created volume in next step (which is not possible in this way) and also want to test on adding the delete on termination flag at AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment step. I said test because, I am not sure it can be added at that step.

Answer (score 0):

That was quite fascinating, seeing how the instance stops!

When using **Amazon Linux 2**, it can be fixed by changing:

```
"DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
```

into:

```
"DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
```

Or, it can be fixed by using **Amazon Linux** (version 1) with `/dev/sda1`.

However, this doesn't fix your `VolumeAttachment` issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until I changed the AMI in my template. Initially, I was testing with Linux AMI in the N.Virginia region where it failed but when I used a CENTOS AMI that I had subscribed to it works.